# Button doesn't open new activity

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have a "inicio" activity with viewpager and have a button in one page inside of the viewpager , but when i click on it nothing happens.

I've tried every mode i found on internet cuz it nothing happens or "has stopped working"

I dont know what to do. It's simpliest thing ( open a activity ) 
but dont know why it dont works....

I think that maybe it is opened in background by the viewpager...

inicio . java

```
package com.example.vamaro.vamaroapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.vamaro.vamaroapp.R;

public class inicio extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.iniciopagerp);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new inicioAdapter());

    }
    public class inicioAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            int[] layouts={R.layout.inicioslide,R.layout.activity_casasslide,R.layout.deptoslide};
            @Override
    public int getCount(){
                return layouts.length;
            }
            @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
           return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
            }
            @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,int position) {
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View vamaro1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inicioslide, container,false);
                View vamaro2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_casasslide, container,false);
                View vamaro3 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.deptoslide, container,false);
                View viewarr[] = { vamaro1,vamaro2,vamaro3};
                container.addView(viewarr[position]);
                return viewarr[position];
            }
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container,int position, Object object){
                container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
            }

}
}
```

and the casasslider . java

```
package com.example.vamaro.vamaroapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class casasslide extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_casasslide);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivityTotalC();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openActivityTotalC(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TotalCasas.class);
        casasslide.this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the error logs

Comment: @Blood21 I recommend you start to debug the code, to see which part you reach, and which part you don't. Is the activity created? Is the button instantiated? Is the button's callback onClick() entered?

Comment: post your error log here

Comment: how does it relate to `javascript`?

Answer (score 0):

you said your `button` is inside one of `viewpager` pages

but you've defined your `button` inside `casasslide` `activity`.

then where is the `view pager` page?

there should be a `fragment` in the `viewPager` that has the `button`.
and the `button` should be defined there, not in the `casasslide`

Comment: It isnt without fragment:o in the inicio theres the viewpager

Comment: you are just using casasslide layout, not its activity. you should define the button inside the inicio activity, or a single fragment that your layout is assigned  to it. dont forget to pass the fragment to viewpager, not layout

Comment: idk why i get crazy with this .... too simple! xd thanks Mohamad Rostami , i have to define it in the viewpager's java not in the layout's java because it is not in use... THANKS

Answer (score 0):

That is alredy activity you don't need to write **getactivity()** or anything.

**just this**

```
Intent I = new Intent (this,Next.class);
startActivity(i);
```

**if that working then debug your code and check onclick() called or not**

happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change from this

```
public void openActivityTotalC(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TotalCasas.class);
    casasslide.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

To this

```
public void openActivityTotalC(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TotalCasas.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

It should solve the problem. Otherwise you might need to post your Error log so other can help you to debug.